# Persist and unpersist in Spark while using same variable during the entire ETL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, persist

How will `persist()` and `unpersist()` work if all steps of my etl process would have the same variable name?
e.g:

```
df =  new dataframe created by reading json for instance i dunno
df.persist()
df = df.withColumn(some_transformation)
df = df.another_transofrmation
df = df.probably_even_more_transformations
df.unpersist()
```

1. What exactly will be persisted and unpersisted?
2. Are `persist()` and `unpersist()` methods actions or transformations?
3. What is better `spark.catalog.clearCache()` or `unpersist()` after every `persist()`

thank you kindly beforehand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark, [`persist`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.spark.persist.html) and [`unpersist`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unpersist.html) are used to manage memory and disk usage when working with DataFrames.

Your scenario:

```bash
+-------------------+    +-------------------+    +-------------------------------+
|                   |    |                   |    |                               |
| Read JSON to df   | -> | df.persist()      | -> | Transformations on df         |
|                   |    | (Stores df in     |    | (df keeps getting reassigned) |
|                   |    | memory/disk)      |    |                               |
+-------------------+    +-------------------+    +-------------------------------+
                                   |                                 |
                                   V                                 V
                          +-------------------+         +--------------------------------+
                          |                   |         |                                |
                          | Data is persisted |         | Reassignments do not affect    |
                          | during all these  |         | persisted data until unpersist |
                          | transformations   |         | is called                      |
                          |                   |         |                                |
                          +-------------------+         +--------------------------------+
                                                                      |
                                                                      V
                                                            +--------------------+
                                                            |                    |
                                                            | df.unpersist()     |
                                                            | (Frees up storage) |
                                                            |                    |
                                                            +--------------------+
```

So:

1. **What will be persisted and unpersisted?**

   The DataFrame `df` is persisted after the `persist()` method is called. All transformations applied to `df` after this point do not affect the persisted data until `unpersist()` is called. When you reassign `df` with transformations, the original persisted DataFrame remains in memory/disk until `unpersist()`.
2. **Are `persist()` and `unpersist()` methods actions or transformations?**

   `persist()` and `unpersist()` are not actions or transformations in the typical Spark sense. They are methods to manage storage. `persist()` hints to Spark to keep the DataFrame in memory or disk, and `unpersist()` frees up the storage. They do not trigger computations like actions, and do not create new DataFrames like transformations.
3. **What is better `spark.catalog.clearCache()` or `unpersist()` after every `persist()`?**

   - `unpersist()`: Specifically removes the persistence of the DataFrame it is called on. It is more controlled and precise when you know which DataFrame you no longer need.
   - `spark.catalog.clearCache()`: Clears all cached DataFrames in the Spark session. It is more of a global reset, useful when you want to make sure all cached data is freed, but it is less precise.

In your ETL process, it is more typical to use `unpersist()` when you are done with a specific DataFrame to free up resources. `clearCache()` can be used at the end of the process or when you would like to make sure a clean slate regarding all cached data.

See also "[Spark – Difference between Cache and Persist?](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-difference-between-cache-and-persist/)" from [Naveen Nelamali](https://www.linkedin.com/in/naveen-nelamali-65007815), Oct. 2023

Both `cache()` and `persist()` are optimization techniques that store intermediate computations of RDDs, DataFrames, and Datasets so they can be reused in subsequent actions. The key difference is that `cache()` defaults to storing data in memory (`MEMORY_ONLY`), while `persist()` allows specifying the storage level, including `MEMORY_AND_DISK`, which is the default for DataFrames and Datasets.

- The `persist()` method can be used without arguments, defaulting to the `MEMORY_AND_DISK` storage level, or with a `StorageLevel` argument to specify different storage levels like `MEMORY_ONLY`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`, etc…
- The `unpersist()` method is used to remove the persisted DataFrame or Dataset from memory or storage. It has a boolean argument that, when set, blocks the operation until all blocks are deleted.

Spark automatically monitors `persist()` and `cache()` calls and may drop persisted data if not used, following a least-recently-used (LRU) algorithm. It is noted that caching in Spark is a lazy operation, meaning the DataFrame or Dataset will not be cached until an action triggers it.

In the context of your ETL process, where the same variable name is used throughout, the `persist()` and `unpersist()` methods control the storage and release of the DataFrame at different stages of the process.
The DataFrame is kept in the specified storage level (default `MEMORY_AND_DISK` for DataFrames) during transformations until `unpersist()` is explicitly called.
That allows for optimized performance by avoiding recomputation of the DataFrame at each transformation stage.